# Let $f(x)=(x+a)(x+b)(x+c) +(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$. Find all factors of $f(x)$

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let $f(x)=(x+a)(x+b)(x+c) +(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$. Find all factors of $f(x)$. Hence find the remainder of $2020 \times 2025\times 2027$ when divided by 2017.

When $x=0$ , $f(0)=0$. Therefore $(x-0)$ is a factor.

Then $f(x)\equiv x(Ax^2+Bx+C) \equiv (x+a)(x+b)(x+c) +(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$

Thus by comparing coefficients we have that $$A=2, B=0 , C=ab+bc+ac$$

How can I find the remainder by putting suitable values for $x,a,b,c$ ?

Comment: It is a cubic polynomial. Once you factor $x$ out the rest is quadratic. Therefore you can factor it using the quadratic formula. $2x(x^2+ab+bc+ ac)=2x(x-i\sqrt{ab+bc+ac})(x+i\sqrt{ab+bc+ac})$

Comment: The second part of the question I would solve it without using the first part. We have that $2020 \times 2025\times 2027=(2017+3)\times(2017+8)\times(2017+11)$. This is congruent to $3\times 8\times 11=264$ mod 2017.

Comment: @Angelo How is the accepted answer addressing the "find the remainder of 2020×2025×2027 when divided by 2017" part of your question?

Comment: Is this what is called an uncomfortable silence, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: prove the $f(x)$ has the form $$f(x)=2\,x \left( ab+ac+bc+{x}^{2} \right) $$

Comment: Posting an "answer" which does not address a question which is itself lacking context... there is a kind of art here.

Comment: there are many open questions for you here!

Comment: (+1) Sure I'm nitpicking, but I'd prefer $ab+bc+ca$ :o)

Comment: Apparently, 3 users think this post is addressing the "find the remainder of 2020×2025×2027 when divided by 2017" part of the question? Oh well...